# Selenium and Java: How do I get all of the text after a WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am coding a program in Java using WebDriver and am having a little bit of trouble getting the text after the select webElement.

The HTML code for the part of the website that I want is as follows:

```
    <select name="language" id="langSelect" style="width:100px;">
            <option value="1"  >Français</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="content">

    
            <div id="Pagination"></div>
    <div id="mid">
              </div>
  </div>
```

The textbox class codes for a search bar and a drop down bar of languages

My Java code is currently able to open chrome using the chrome driver and is able to type into the search bar. I am however not able to get the text that results from the entry.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWbaD.jpg)

In the image here, I entered "avoir" into the search bar, and I want all of the text inside the boxes after which do not seem to have any id's or names to be used inside the xpath.

Can someone please help me in finding how to get and save the text from those fields after the dropdown language menu?

Thank you in advance!

The code I have so far:

```
//import statements not shown
    public class WebScraper  {
    public WebScraper() {
    
    }

    public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    public void openTestSite() {
   
        driver.navigate().to(the URL for the website);
    }


    public void enter(String word) {

         WebElement query_editbox = 
         driver.findElement(By.id("query")); 
         query_editbox.sendKeys(word);
         query_editbox.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

    }

    public void getText()  {
        //List<WebElement> searchResults = 
        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='mid']/div")); 
        // Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new 
        OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("status.txt"), 
        "utf-8"));
        //int[] index = {0};

    WebElement result=driver.findElement(By.id("mid"));
    System.out.println(result.getText());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");        
    System.out.println("Hello");

    WebScraper webSrcaper = new WebScraper();
    webSrcapper.openTestSite();
    webSrcapper.enter("avoir");
    webSrcapper.getText();
    System.out.println("Hello");

}
```

}

Comment: Can you check the image? We couldn't access the Image.

Comment: Sorry about that. Can you please look at the image I posted now? it's the "enter image description here" link. Thanks!

Comment: So, you want to get all the content form the displayed 3 box right?

Comment: Yes, that was my goal.

Comment: Okay. I have updated the answer. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have specified three approaches to extract the text from the result box. Please check all the approaches and use the required approach.

1. If you want to extract all the text, then you can find the element of the result box and then you can get the Text from that.

   ```
   WebElement result=driver.findElement(By.id("mid"));
   System.out.println(result.getText());
   ```
2. If you want to extract the Text based on the Section by section, then you can go with the below approach,

   ```
   List<WebElement> sectionList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='mid']/div"));
   int i=0;
   for(WebElement element:sectionList){
       System.out.println("Section "+i+":"+element.getText());
       i++;
   }
   ```
3. If you want to extract the text from specific section, then you can do with the below approach

   ```
       List<WebElement> sectionList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='mid']/div"));
   int i=0;
   //Inorder to get the Section 3 Content
   int section=2;
   for(WebElement element:sectionList){
       if(section==i){
           System.out.println("Section "+i+":"+element.getText());
       }
       i++;
   }
   ```

**Edit:** To address followup question

I would suggest to use some explicit wait after doing some action which resulting in some element rendering. In your code, after doing some modification, I am getting the result as expected.

1. In `openTestSite` method, I have just added the explicit wait to ensure the page load after loading the URL
2. In `enter` method, actually you are getting the autocomplete suggestion after entering the query value .So, we need to just select the value from the autocomplete.
3. In `getText` method, Search result is taking more time.So, we need to add some explicit wait using any one of the dynamically loading element locator.

**Code:**

**openTestSite Method:**

```
    public void openTestSite() {

    //driver.navigate().to(the URL for the website);
    driver.get("https://wonef.fr/try/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //Explicit wait is added after the Page load
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("WoNeF"));
}
```

**enter Method:**

```
public void enter(String word) {

    WebElement query_editbox =
            driver.findElement(By.id("query"));
    query_editbox.sendKeys(word);
    //AutoComplete is happening even after sending the Enter Key.
    // So, Value needs to be selected from the autocomplete
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='autocomplete']/div")));
    List<WebElement> matchedList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='autocomplete']/div"));

    System.out.println(matchedList.size());
    for(WebElement element : matchedList){
        if(element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(word)){
            element.click();
        }
    }
    //query_editbox.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
}
```

**getText Method**:

```
public void getText()  {
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='mid']/div")));
    WebElement result=driver.findElement(By.id("mid"));
    System.out.println(result.getText());
}
```

I have tested with the above modified code and it is working fine.

Comment: Thank you! However, I am having a slight problem. System.out.println isn't printing anything to my console. I am using eclipse on a mac. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: oh... I am using Windows Eclipse and getting the result without any issue. Whether you are getting atleast "Approach 1:" in Console?

Comment: No, that is not working either. However, other system.out statements are working. For example, in the main method after calling the method that performs these steps and is supposed to print something, I printed "hello" and that appeared in the console window. So, I am kind of confused why this isn't working.

Comment: I suspect this method might not be called. can you share me the calling method along with other sysout statement .

Comment: Can you please refer to my original post? I just edited it to include the code I have so far.

Comment: Actually Autocomplete is causing the problem. I have edited the answer based on your code. Please use the edited code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Just one last clarification, do I just print out the contents of the matchedList now? And I do not need the old getText method anymore right?

Comment: Sorry, actually, the code is working for option 3. However, it only works when i = 2. When I change i to 0, the code doesn't print out the contents of the first box; it doesn't print anything actually. Do you know why? Sorry for bothering you so much.

Comment: Can you check by adding some explicit wait in your getText method as well

Comment: Can you check by adding some explicit wait in your getText method as well ? I have edited the answer and updated the getText() method as well.

Comment: I just tried the updated getText method and I just simply got a space between the number printed in other methods and the Hello printed at the end.

Comment: It looks search is randomly taking more time. You can use the updated Explicit wait (using Xpath) . you will get a result without any further issue:)

Comment: Actually, sorry, it's working now! Thank you so much for all of your help!!

Comment: Glad to know that it is working!!! Please give the upvote by clicking on the up arrow, If you are satisfied with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to inspect the relevant results for your query, common strategy would be to load a list of search results:

```
List<WebElement> searchResults = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='mid']/div"));
```

Now you can use stream to iterate over the list and extract your relevant text, by getting the text from child elements of each result:

```
int[] index = {0};
searchResults.stream().forEach(result -> {
    System.out.println("Printing query result of index: " + index[0]);
    result.findElements(By.xpath(".//*")).stream().forEach(webElement -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(webElement.getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    });
    index[0]++;
});
```

And you would get the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will try this, and hopefully it will work.